# How to apply a NTILE function to a SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So im trying to establish quantiles over the number of attentions received by some customers, **but leaving NULLs and 0 out of the sample** and placing them in the 0 and null quantil before applying NTILES function, I'm using this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RPS_Ntiles (@data int,@percentil int)  
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
SELECT 
  NTILE(@percentil) OVER(ORDER BY @data DESC) as QUINTIL
  WHERE @data > 0
UNION
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(int,@data) = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN @data is NULL THEN NULL
    END AS QUINTIL
WHERE @data = 0 or @data = NULL
```

Then I'm applying it using CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT t.QUINTIL,D.[atenciones]
FROM table as D
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[RPS_NTiles](CONVERT(int,D.[atenciones]),5) as t
ORDER BY D.[atenciones] DESC
```

The result of this query is effective at leaving 0 and nulls out of the NTILEs function but the rest of the data is placed entirely in just 1 quintil like this:

```
+------------+---------+--+
| Atenciones | Quintil |  |
+------------+---------+--+
|         0  |       0 |  |
|         0  |       0 |  |
|       NULL |    NULL |  |
|         1  |       1 |  |
|         3  |       1 |  |
|         4  |       1 |  |
|         7  |       1 |  |
|        46  |       1 |  |
|        59  |       1 |  |
+------------+---------+--+
```

And I'm looking for something like this:

```
+------------+---------+--+
| Atenciones | Quintil |  |
+------------+---------+--+
|         0  |       0 |  |
|         0  |       0 |  |
|       NULL |    NULL |  |
|         1  |       1 |  |
|         3  |       2 |  |
|         4  |       2 |  |
|         7  |       3 |  |
|        46  |       4 |  |
|        59  |       5 |  |
+------------+---------+--+
```

Comment: `cross apply` wirks per row, of course there's only NTILE 1 for a single row, you can't do this in a scalar function.

Comment: @dnoeth that makes lot of sense, now I'm stucked because i cant figure it out how to apply this function to any column in any table.

Comment: You would need a kind of Table Valued Function, which don't support dynamic SQL (afaik). Using the CASE Gordon proposed isn't much more complicated than your CORSS APPLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why define your own function?  You can express this using `case` logic:

```
select (case when Atenciones is null or Atenciones = 0
             then Atenciones
             else ntile(5) over (partition by (case when Atenciones is null or Atenciones = 0 then 1 else 2 end)
                                 order by Atenciones
                                ) 
        end)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will be used with other tables names and columns, so I need it in a function so it can be specified the number of quantiles and the name of the column.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . It works.  They are in separate partitions, so those calculations are ignored.

Comment: How would you generalize it for any column and table name?

Comment: @schwerter2 . . . I don't understand the question.  You would just use whatever columns and tables you wanted to use for the logic.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm trying to make a generalized way so I just have to change 2 parameters (table and column name) in a function and make the procedure explained above.
I guess sql-server won't allow that :(

Comment: @schwerter2 . . . You might be able to develop such a function.  It will be way, way slower than using the built in analytic functions.